# Spring Tool Suite 4 how to change deployment server

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, spring-boot, tomcat

How to change deployment server for project in spring tool suite 4 eclipse to another A.S. like another tomcat outside embembed tomcat?

So I have dowloaded Spring Tool Suite package pre installed in eclipse from [here](https://spring.io/tools) and followed a basic tutorial to start building a maven REST webservice app.
Everything works very well, I have well builded project structure, connects to Postgres DB... etc.

Later I noticed that this app runs on an internal tomcat server in this development "pack", meaning there are no servers displayed.

[image]

I tried to add to eclipse the latest tomcat server ( 10 at the time ) but my project doesn´t show up to add.

[image]

[image]

[image: Spring Tool Suite 4]

Answer (score 0):

You need to override the properties in the parent pom.xml .

```
<properties>
......
    <tomcat.version>10.0.11</tomcat.version>
......
<properties>
```

[This link](https://www.springboottutorial.com/spring-boot-starter-parent) can be helpful in your case .

Comment: Thx but the answear to this question is much more complex...

Your link helped me in my search...i read this instead [ https://spring.io/blog/2014/03/07/deploying-spring-boot-applications ] and basically understood what i need to do , to deploy my project in other AS like another tomcat or JavaEE old deployment style like a war file. Wich is my goal.